# Report Crashes or Uncaught Exceptions using GTM for Android & iOS

Tags: android, ios, google-tag-manager, google-analytics-sdk

I'm trying to implement Google Analytics Crashes/Uncaught Exceptions tracking using Google Tag Manager in Android & iOS. I'm able to track Caught Exceptions using the Exception tag avialable in GTM.

I have checked the reference guide for [Android](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tagmanager/package-summary) with no references related to exceptions.

EDIT: I have created a crash to check if it is reported or not

`9052-9052/com.android.sample E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main                                                                                             Process: com.android.sample, PID: 9052                                                                                                  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference                                                                                                      at com.android.sample.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:61)                                                                                                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5242)                                                                                                      at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:10540)                                                                                                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21179)                                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)                                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)                                                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)                                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6873)                                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)                                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)                                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)                                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)`

I was thinking to push a dataLayer event when the app crashes however I wonder if developer will have control to push an event during/after the crash.

Please suggest if there is any way possible to track these things using GTM.

Comment: Do you have some crashlogs for these crashes?

Comment: @shpasta I have added the sample stack trace in question

Answer (score 0):

The reason of the listed crash is not GTM. You are calling `setText()` method on textView object, that is actually null in `MainActivity`.

Comment: yeah, I want this to be reported to GTM; at least number (i.e., 1 crash has occured)